# Why is an ARTrackedObject flickering/rendering badly even though ARMarkers are working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, artoolkit

I've been using the Example NFT Scenes from the ARToolKit Unity Package and also created my own from scratch but have been experiencing some sort of z-fighting, culling or camera clipping issue (I suspect).

When the marker is found, the tracked game object (a simple cube in the example or whatever) partially renders and flickers but disappears/reappears rapidly when the marker is moved. Marker Found, Tracking and Lost events are firing correctly and on any event receivers. The tracked objects are rendering (badly) with the correct spatial dimensions related to the marker.

I've tried adjusting the camera clipping near/far planes in the ARController but with no success. Increasing the Near Plane value above ~0.25 starts to render black artifacts in the shape of the TrackedObject's geometry over the video layer.

This is on a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) running macOS 10.12.4 , using Unity 5.6.1f and I'm using the ARUnity5-5.3.2.unitypackage download.
I did have to disable some of the imports from that package as they were trying to overwrite Unity Application dlls

How can I get Tracked Objects to render correctly?

Comment: Two things that come to mind: Are you using a webcam or the build in camera? Did you calibrate your camera?

Comment: I'm using the built in camera on the laptop. I haven't calibrated it, it seemed like the ARController had selected a relevant calibration profile already. Have you seen issues from calibration like this? The Marker is being tracked as far as I can tell. Is this a limitation of ARToolKit, would a user always need to calibrate their camera? (say on iOS or Android)

Comment: It is selecting a default camera calibration if nothing else is given. Which might or might not work. So yes it might be a calibration issue. Regarding your 2nd question on iOS and Android ARToolKit provides a web service that holds the needed calibrations and downloads them when needed. That is part of the ToolKit

Answer (score 0):

today I had to deal with the same problem, I had to change the clear flags in the camera to depth only. The problem is that ARToolkit change it by default to Don’t clear, that work for me but that is because my CPU don't have a GPU, but yours should be fine, try running the program and then changeing the clear flag to depth only, if enverything starts to render maybe there is a problem with the GPU or with the way that you are rendering yor object.